# Error while comparing in shell

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to search a pattern(trailer) and if it occures more than once in a file, I need those filenames displayed

```
    for f in *.txt
    do
     if((tail -n 1 $f | grep '[9][9][9]*' | wc -l) -ge 2);
      then
       echo " The file $f has more than one trailer"
     fi
    done
```

Comment: Apart from the fact you should add more info, why do you have `(tail -n 1 $f | grep '[9][9][9]*' | wc -l)`, it should be `$(tail...`

Comment: That is un-necessary. pls consider if(grep '[9][9][9]' | wc -l) -ge 2);

Comment: Yve : check.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `-ge'
check.sh: line 23: ` if((tail -n 1 $f | grep '[9][9][9]*' | wc -l) -ge 2);'

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: @Karoly Horvath : hi karoly thanks for the link

Comment: changed my code like **for f in *.txt do n1=`grep '[9][9][9]*' $f | wc -l` if["$n1" -ge "$n2"]; then echo "The file $f has more than one trailer" fi done** but is still get the same error _check.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `then' check.sh: line 24: ` if["$n1" -ge "$n2"]; then'_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your most crying syntax error is that `-ge` is an operator for the `[ … ]` or `[[ … ]]` conditional construct. It doesn't have a chance the way you wrote the program. `-ge` needs a number on both sides, and what you have on the left is a command. You probably meant to have the output of the command, which would need the command substitution syntax: `$(…)`. That's

```
if [ $(tail -n 1 $f | grep '[9][9][9]*' | wc -l) -ge 2 ]; then
```

This is syntactically correct but will never match. `tail -n 1 $f` outputs exactly one line (unless the file is empty), so `grep` sees at most one line, so `wc -l` prints either 0 or 1.

If you want to search the pattern on more than one line, change your `tail` invocation. While you're at it, you can change `grep … | wc -l` to `grep -c`; both do exactly the same thing, which is to count matching lines. For example, to search in the last 42 lines:

```
if [ $(tail -n 42 -- "$f" | grep -c '[9][9][9]*') -ge 2 ]; then
```

If you want to search for two matches on the last lines, that's different. `grep` won't help because it determines whether each line matches or not, it doesn't look for multiple matches per line. If you want to look for multiple non-overlapping matches on the last line, repeat the pattern, allowing arbitrary text in between. You're testing if the pattern is present or not, so you only need to test the return status of `grep`, you don't need its output (hence the `-q` option).

```
if tail -n 1 -- "$f" | grep -q '[9][9][9]*.*[9][9][9]*'; then
```

I changed the `tail` invocations to add `--` in case a file name begins with `-` (otherwise, `tail` would interpret it as an option) and to have double quotes around the file name (in case it contains whitespace or `\[*?`). These are good habits to get into. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions `"$foo"` and command substitutions `"$(foo)"` unless you know that the substitution will result in a whitespace-separated list of glob patterns.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I have finally completed the script.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -n 1 $f` will produce (at most) *one* line of output, which is fed to `grep`, which can then produce by definition at most *one* line of output, which means that the output of `wc` will never be more than 1, and will especially never be greater than 2. Aside from the syntax issues mentioned in other comments/answers, I think this logic is probably one of the core problems.

Comment: twalberg: you are correct. The problem is with the syntax and the logic. Finally i got it done. 
`n1=`grep '[9][9][9]*' $f | wc -l`
 if [ $n1 -ge 2 ]; then ` 
and this is working perfectly.